# L5.6 orderBy() in combination with paginate() returns the same row multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, eloquent

Controller:

```
public function index($devicetype)
{
    $devices = Device::where('device_type', $devicetype)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(config('myapp.pagination.items_per_page'));
    return view('devices.general.index', compact('devices'));
}
```

I am getting the same device multiple times on different pages in my blade.php view.

But `dd(Device::where('device_type', $devicetype)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get());` gives me a correct collection without multiple entries.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are many records with the same `created_at` value. To fix this, add a second order by id to remove the duplicated show in pagination:

```
$devices = Device::where('device_type', $devicetype)
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->paginate(config('myapp.pagination.items_per_page'));
return view('devices.general.index', compact('devices'));
```

Comment: shame on me. How could I have overseen that?? THANK you very very much!!

Comment: @titonior, that's okay :) Happens to the best of us. Happy coding!